# How to use gekko variables as componets of an array?

Tags: python, gekko, minimization

I need to solve a minimization problem that involves vectors, I am using cern's root and Gekko to try solving the problem. But I kind of need to build root four-vectors/three with Gekko variables to make the operations easier.

Suposse that I have x1,x2 and x3 as gekko variables. I want to build an array something like:

> x = ( x1*sin(x2)*cos(x3) , x1*sin(x2)*sin(x3) , x1 )

Is that possible? And can I do operations with it? Like:

> m.equation(x*x ==20)

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with the three variables, one equation, and a vector operation with the dot product:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x1,x2,x3 = m.Array(m.Var,3)
x = [x1*m.sin(x2)*m.cos(x3), \
     x1*m.sin(x2)*m.sin(x3), \
     x1]
m.Equation(np.dot(x,x)==0)
m.solve(disp=True)
print(x1.value,x2.value,x3.value)
```

Gekko produces a solution `[0,0,0]` when the dot product is `0`. It correctly reports an infeasible solution when the dot product is `20`.

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
    1  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   7.099999987985939E-003 sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

The solution specifics aren't important here, but this is just a demonstration of using arrays and vector operations. Use `m.sum()` instead of `sum()` if the vector is very large. Likewise, use `m.sum([xi**2 for xi in x])` instead of `np.dot(x,x)` for large `x` vectors.

The CERN `ROOT` package is a nice complement to the optimization capabilities of `gekko` to visualize and explore solutions. The `ROOT` functions can help with pre-processing and post-processing of the optimization solutions but probably can't be used directly in Gekko expressions. Gekko performs automatic differentiation to give exact 1st and 2nd derivative information to gradient-based solvers. Most other packages aren't configured to provide that information or the interface that the solvers need with sparse matrices.

Comment: I have 6 variables in my problem, and i defined two arrays with the gekko variables:                    x_l = [x1*m.sin(x3)*m.cos(x5), x1*m.sin(x3)*m.sin(x5), x1]
x_l2 = [x2*m.sin(x4)*m.cos(x6), x2*m.sin(x4)*m.sin(x6), x2]                                                          And i tried to do a np.dot() with a 3d numpy array, and it returned me: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (3,)  . o you have a clue of why this happened?

Comment: Could you create a new question with the minimal code that shows the error (similar to what I posted)?